# ¿Cómo validar que una sharedPreference existe?

Tags: kotlin, sharedpreferences

'''
si una preferencia existe, que me cargue la actividad con el valor , y si no tiene ningún valor que me envié a la actividad de inicio donde ingrese el valor en el editext  y poder almacenar el valor en la sharedpreference
'''
class SegundaActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
lateinit var preferences:SharedPreferences
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_segunda)

    var btnsalir=findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnsalir)
    preferences=getSharedPreferences("SHARED",Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val editor:SharedPreferences.Editor=preferences.edit()
    val nombre=preferences.getString("NOMBRE","")
    tvnombre.text=nombre
    
    //validartv()

    btnsalir.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        val editor:SharedPreferences.Editor=preferences.edit()
        editor.clear()
        editor.apply()

        val intent=Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    })
}
private fun validartv():Boolean{
    var tvnombre=findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvnombre)
    if (preferences.getBoolean("SHARED", false)) {
        val intent=Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        return false
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"bienvenido de vuelta",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    return true
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Puedes definir un valor por defecto para que sea devuelto en caso de que el dato no exista.

Main Activity:

```
lateinit var preferences:SharedPreferences
private val NONE="none"
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    
    preferences=getSharedPreferences("SHARED", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val nombre=preferences.getString("NOMBRE",NONE)
        if(!nombre.equals(NONE)){//Si el dato que buscas existe
            cambiaActivity(nombre)
        }
        //Aqui va el código que despliega la inerfaz y solicita el nombre al usuario
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_kotlin)
}

private fun cambiaActivity(nombre:String){
    val intent=Intent(this,SegundaActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("NOMBRE",nombre)
    startActivity(intent)
    finish()
}
```

El evento del botón con el que el usuario confirma los datos deberia ser como este

```
override fun onClick(view:View){
    val editor=getSharedPreferences("SHARED", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
    editor.putString("NOMBRE",editText.text.toString())
    editor.apply()
    cambiaActivity(editText.text.toString())
}
```

Tu segunda activity debe incluir lo siguiente

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_segunda)

        var btnsalir=findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnsalir)
        val nombre=intent.extras.getString("NOMBRE",NONE)//También puedes definir un valor por defecto 
        tvnombre.text=nombre

        //validartv()

        btnsalir.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            /*val editor:SharedPreferences.Editor=preferences.edit()
            editor.clear()
            editor.apply()*/ //Esto no es necesario

            val intent=Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        })
    }
```

Comment: entonces en el MainActivity ya no iría sharedpreference , sino solo en el activity destino?

Comment: Si vas a compartir datos mediante sharedPreferences uno de los activitys debe hacer el regisro mediante Editor.apply o Editor.commit, muentras que el otro debe recuperar los datos mediante sharedPreferences.get. Si vas a compartir usando los extras del intent, no es necesario el uso de shared preferences en ninguno de los 2 activitys, a menos que quieras conservar los datos para recuperarlos la proxima vez que se inicie tu app.

Comment: exacto , eso es lo que quiero, conservar el dato cuando se inicie y que cuando se abra la app , muestre el valor que ingrese

Comment: Ya edité la respuesta

Comment: me ayudo a entenderlo , muchas gracias